# Solving a 2-D Laplace equation with boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I am having a problem solving a 2-D Laplace equation with 4 boundary conditions.
I want to solve this differential equation(pde) of phi2[x,y] in Fourier series.

Note that phi1[x] is previously solved 2nd-order polynomial function of x.

```
phi1[x_] := (eox esi nd q tch tox + esi^2 nd q tox^2 - 2 eox^2 esi vfb + 2 eox^2 esi vg + eox^2 nd q tch x - eox^2 nd q x^2)/(2 eox^2 esi)
```

To solve pde, I write in my code:

```
eqn2 = D[phi2[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[phi2[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0
bc3 = phi2[x, 0] == vs - phi1[x]
bc4 = phi2[x, l] == vs + vd - phi1[x]
bc5 = phi2[tch + tox esi/eox, y] == 0
bc6 = phi2[-tox esi/eox, y] == 0

Ω = Rectangle[{-tox esi/eox, 0}, {tch + tox esi/eox, l}]

DSolve[{eqn2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6}, phi2[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

I expect the solution would be in forms of Fourier series.
However, the output only repeats my input, not solving differential equation.

Please help me if you guys have some advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

MMa is still in its infancy as far as solving pde's analytically.  Solving this problem by separation of variables is fairly straightforward, although somewhat messy.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

I will simplify your `psi1`

```
phi1[x_] = a + b x + c x^2;
```

The pde

```
eqn2 = D[phi2[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[phi2[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0
```

The boundary conditions

```
bc3 = phi2[x, 0] == vs - phi1[x];
bc4 = phi2[x, l] == vs + vd - phi1[x];
bc5 = phi2[tch + d, y] == 0;
bc6 = phi2[-d, y] == 0;
```

Assume

```
phi2[x_, y_] = X[x] Y[y]

eqn2/phi2[x, y] // Expand
(* X''[x]/X[x] + Y''[y]/Y[y] == 0 *)
```

If we move the `Y` part to the rhs we see that the `X` part is the negative of the `Y` part.  Each side must be equal to a constant.  Let the `X` part be sinusoidal.  So we have.

```
xeq = X''[x]/X[x] == -alpha^2

yeq = Y''[y]/Y[y] == alpha^2
```

DSolve the `xeq` for `X[x]`

```
DSolve[xeq, X[x], x] // Flatten;
X1 = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};
```

And the `yeq`

```
DSolve[yeq, Y[y], y] // Flatten;
Y1 = Y[y] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4};
```

Convert the above to trig

```
ExpToTrig[Y1] // Collect[#, {Sinh[alpha y], Cosh[alpha y]}] &
(* (c3 - c4) Sinh[alpha y] + (c3 + c4) Cosh[alpha y] *)

Y1 = % /. {c3 - c4 -> c3, c3 + c4 -> c4}
(* c3 Sinh[alpha y] + c4 Cosh[alpha y] *)
```

We have the pieces.  Put them together as

```
phi2[x_, y_] = X1 Y1;
```

To start, look at `bc5`

```
bc5
(* (c3 Sinh[alpha y] + c4 Cosh[alpha y]) (c1 Cos[alpha (d + tch)] + 
    c2 Sin[alpha (d + tch)]) == 0 *)

Solve[bc5, c2]  
(* {{c2 -> -c1 Cot[alpha (d + tch)]}} *)

c2 = c2 /. %[[1]];
```

Now `bc6`

```
bc6
(* (c3 Sinh[alpha y] + 
    c4 Cosh[alpha y]) (c1 Sin[alpha d] Cot[alpha (d + tch)] + 
    c1 Cos[alpha d]) == 0 *)

bc6[[1, 1]] // Collect[#, c1] &
(* c1 (Sin[alpha d] Cot[alpha (d + tch)] + Cos[alpha d])*)

%/c1;

alphaeq = % == 0
(* Sin[alpha d] Cot[alpha (d + tch)] + Cos[alpha d] == 0 *)
```

The above determines values of alpha.  It is a transcendental equation solved numerically, once constants of the problem are assigned. There are an infinite number of then and the solution becomes an infinite sum over the values of alphas.  Ignore the sum for now.

```
phi2[x, y] // Simplify
(* c1 Csc[alpha (d + tch)] Sin[
  alpha (d + tch - x)] (c3 Sinh[alpha y] + c4 Cosh[alpha y]) *)
```

Combine constants. `c1` is redundant

```
c1 = 1

phi2[x_, y_] = phi2[x, y] // Simplify
```

Now

```
bc3
(* c4 Csc[alpha (d + tch)] Sin[alpha (d + tch - x)] == -a - b x - c x^2 +
   vs *)
```

Use orthogonalities of the alphas to solve for `c4`.

```
c4*Csc[alpha*(d + tch)]*Integrate[Sin[alpha*(d + tch - x)]^2, {x, -d, tch + d}] == 
   Integrate[(-a - b*x - c*x^2 + vs)*Sin[alpha*(d + tch - x)]^2, {x, -d, tch + d}]//Simplify;

c4rule = Solve[%, c4] // Simplify;
```

Keep thing simple.  Don't assign it yet.

```
bc4

(* Csc[alpha (d + tch)] Sin[
   alpha (d + tch - x)] (c3 Sinh[alpha l] + c4 Cosh[alpha l]) == -a - 
  b x - c x^2 + vd + vs *)
```

Now orthogonality to solve for `c3`.

```
Csc[alpha*(d + tch)]*(c3*Sinh[alpha*l] + c4*Cosh[alpha*l])*
    Integrate[Sin[alpha*(d + tch - x)]^2, {x, -d, tch + d}] == 
   Integrate[(-a - b*x - c*x^2 + vd + vs)*Sin[alpha*(d + tch - x)]^2, {x, -d, tch + d}]//Simplify;

c3rule = Solve[%, c3] // Simplify;
```

Now assign `c3`, `c4`

```
c4 = c4 /. c4rule[[1]] // Simplify;

c3 = c3 /. c3rule[[1]] // Simplify;
```

We have solved for all the constants satisfying the boundary conditions which gives us `phi2[x,y]` in terms of `alpha`.  The total solution is an infinite sum over all the `alpha`s, determined by numerically solving the equation for `alpha` once numerical values for all your constants are specified.  I have not printed the output for the later values of these calculations because they are lengthy.